# Разбить List на List по 10 элементов

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть лист. С каждым элементом я в отдельном потоке провожу работу. Обьектов много. Хочу раздить лись по группам (10 обьектов в группе), и каждую группу в отдельном потоке обработать.

Как я делаю сейчас:

```
list.parallelStream().map(key -> Some actions)
```

Как мне реализовать это?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно предварительно разбить список на части

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> chunkify(List<T> list, int chunkSize){
    List<List<T>> chunks = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += chunkSize) {
        List<T> chunk = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(i, Math.min(list.size(), i + chunkSize)));
        chunks.add(chunk);
    }

    return chunks;
}

chunkify(bigList, 10).parallelStream()
                     .map(...)
                     ...
```

Comment: А если это будет Set?

Comment: @ks_on_v можно и Set разбить, но потребление памяти станет неэффективным. В приведённом мной примере, все списки используют ту же область памяти, которую использует исходный список.

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать используя библиотеку Guava :

```
Lists.partition(yourListName, 10)
        .parallelStream()
        .forEach(...);
```